# Send Data from Span in EJS to Server Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Using Nodejs, Express, EJS

I see a lot of 'Send Data from Server to Client' but not from Client to Server **AND** sending the data from a  tag not from a form input.

I would like to send the content of a  tag from my ejs page/client to my nodejs/server.

What I'm trying...
**page.ejs**

```
            <div>
                   <form action="/brewery" method="GET">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                           placeholder="search brewery name" 
                           name="search">
                       </div>
                       <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
                   </form>
            </div>

            <div> 
                   <ul>
                       <% searchBreweryList.forEach(function(searchBrewery){ %>
                       <div>
                         <li>
                         Brewery Name: <span><%= searchBrewery.brewery.brewery_name %></span>
                         Brewery ID: <span name="brewID" id="shareBreweryID"><%= searchBrewery.brewery.brewery_id %></span>
                         </li>
                       </div>
                       <% }) %>
                   </ul>
            </div>
```

Then on my server side...
**server.js**

```
app.get('/brewery', async (req, res) => {
  var searchBreweryFound = req.query.search; 
  var isIndie = req.params.brewID
  //console.log(isIndie)
  //console.log(searchBreweryFound)
  try {
    request("https://api.com/v4/search/brewery?access_token=abc123&limit=1&q=" + searchBreweryFound, function (error, response, body) 
    {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        const searchBrewery = JSON.parse(body);
        const searchBreweryList = searchBrewery.response.brewery.items.map(item => item );
        
        res.render('brewery.ejs', {searchBreweryList}); 
        //console.log(searchBreweryList);
      });   
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", e)
  }
  });
```

So the above Get call is just an example where I'm trying to take the result in the client side span that looks like `<span name="brewID">`. Then I'm trying to give that ID number to the server in the var seen as `var isIndie = req.params.brewID`.
But this does not seem to be a method that allows me to pass content from a span in client to server.
What approach should I be taking? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "sending data from client to server". Standard method of sending data from client to server is using XMLHttpRequest (XHR) inside *.js file(s), but based on your code you want to redirect browser window to URL with some parameters. When browser hit your endpoint, for example `/brewery`, server will render *.ejs file and respond to browser with HTML code.

### Redirecting browser with EJS

Below code is based on code you posted.

```js
<div>
  <ul>
    <% searchBreweryList.forEach(function(searchBrewery){ %>
      <div>
        <li>
          Brewery Name: <span>
            <%= searchBrewery.brewery.brewery_name %>
          </span>
          Brewery ID: <span name="brewID" id="shareBreweryID">
            <%= searchBrewery.brewery.brewery_id %>
          </span>
          <!-- Here we create link using parameter of brewery (version with param) -->
          <a href="<%= '/brewery/' + searchBrewery.brewery.brewery_id %>">Go to brewery</a>
          <!-- Version with query param -->
          <a href="<%= '/brewery?id=' + searchBrewery.brewery.brewery_id %>">Go to brewery</a>
        </li>
      </div>
      <% }) %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

After clicking `Go to brewery` browser will hit `/brewery` endpoint with param `brewery_id`. I also noticed that in posted example `var isIndie = req.params.brewID` may not work.

### Bonus: `req.query` vs `req.params`

Both `req.query` and `req.params` are used to get some informations from endpoint URL. However `req.query` and `req.params` are not the same.

#### Using req.query

For endpoint: `/brewery?id=5&q=test`

```js
const id = req.query.id // 5
const q = req.query.q   // 'test'
```

#### Using req.params

To use req params you must place param name somewhere in url of express endpoint.

```js
app.get('/brewery/:id', async (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id
})
```

So to make your example with `req.params` working:

```js
app.get('/brewery/:brewID', async (req, res) => {
  var searchBreweryFound = req.query.search; 
  var isIndie = req.params.brewID

// Rest of your code
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much Maksymilian. Let me try to explain a bit more of what I'm hoping to do. On the client side page.ejs, there is a form input to search via api for a brewery. After clicking the submit/search button, a full brewery name and the brewery's ID (from the api) are rendered in the ejs code seen below the form.
I want to take that Brewery ID from my page.ejs and pass it back to the server. I don't necessarily want to manipulate my query endpoint (unless this is the best way), I simply want to pass that Brewery ID back to the server. I figured there was different method to do this.

Comment: Passing ids and other small amounts of informations (like search query for example) in url query is most popular method of passing data back to server. It's perfect solution for described by you problem. Also, it's widely used in production environments. You can check how youtube.com works with url query. Try to search phrase "Some video", and you browser url will be "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Some+video". Same thing happens when you open particular video. You will see video id in url query: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw"

Comment: ok thanks, good to know I'm following a best practice